# installing RASPBIAN 3.18 + adicional packages into Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've just installed RASPBIAN 3.18 and next packages:

```
wget http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/b/bluez/bluez_4.99- 2_armhf.deb
wget http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/libc/libcap- ng/libcap-ng0_0.6.6-2_armhf.deb
wget http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/r/radvd/radvd_1.8.5- 1_armhf.deb
wget -O kernel.zip http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/nordic/download_resource/41602/5/28710770
unzip kernel.zip
sudo dpkg -i radvd_1.8.5-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libcap-ng0_0.6.6-2_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i bluez_4.99-2_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.17.4-release+_1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.17.4-release+_1_armhf.deb
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Add the following line:

```
kernel=vmlinuz-3.17.4-release+ to config.txt
```

save and exit

```
sudo reboot
```

and when I restart I got an screen more or less as the print screen attached. Any idea ?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing is sure: The rainbow screen means the GPU firmware is loaded, but there is a problem with the kernel image. Which one? Impossible to say from here. Perhaps not found or corrupt. Might be that the kernel you got from www.nordicsemi.com is broken. Might be you have a typo somewhere. But it can also be a faulty SD-card. Or a wrong power supply. According to Google:

In some cases (Stuck on the Rainbow Screen), freezing at this point has been fixed by adding "boot_delay=1" to the config.txt file.

If nothing helps, you probably have to go back to the default Raspian kernel. If you need a more recent kernel than in the default Raspian, you can switch to Raspian testing. The testing kernel should be a bit more recent... and definitely works for me.

This might also help you (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=58151)

Error ACT LED patterns
While booting the ACT LED should blink in an irregular pattern, indicating it is reading from the card. If it starts blinking in a regular (Morse code like) pattern then it is signaling an error.

When it blinks just once: possibly you have a Rpi from Micron. Take a good look at the processor if it says M with an orbit around it, then using the latest software ( after Sept 2013 ) will solve your problem. Also make sure you have a 4Gb SD card: a 2Gb doesn't work in this particular case.

Other patterns that might appear during a failed boot mean:

```
3 flashes: start.elf not found
4 flashes: start.elf not launch-able (corrupt)
7 flashes: kernel.img not found
8 flashes: SDRAM not recognized. You need newer bootcode.bin/start.elf firmware, or your SDRAM is damaged
```

Firmware before 20th October 2012 required loader.bin, and the meaning of the flashes was slightly different:

```
3 flashes: loader.bin not found
4 flashes: loader.bin not launch-able (corrupt)
5 flashes: start.elf not found
6 flashes: start.elf not launch-able
7 flashes: kernel.img not found
```

Comment: Maybe the boot loader cannot find kernel image ... Can you show us partition scheme?